# Cannot install Ubuntu 20 on laptop with windows 10 and NVIDIA Geforce RTX 2080

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 20.04, grub-efi, nvidia-geforce

I have laptop with NVidia Geforce RTX 2080 and Windows 10 installed, and I would like to install second OS, latest Ubuntu 20, but I am not able.

Black Screen after launching Grub option "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu (safe graphics)".

I have read a lot of articles and posts about problems with installing Ubuntu on laptops with NVidia card, all regarding Ubuntu versions up to 19, not the latest one (20). I know that I should turn off Fast Startup in Windows 10, to disable Fast Boot and Safe Boot on UEFI. I know that there are problems with Nvidia card's Nouveau drivers and how to set "nomodeset" (nouveau.modeset=0). What is important, the latest Ubuntu version addresses this issue with new Grub option called "Ubuntu (safe graphics), where "nomodeset" is set by default.

But It does not help, Black Screen as usual, no any logs on screen.

Was anybody able to install latest Ubuntu 20 on laptop with NVIdia RTX card?

How to get logs from installation process to get known what is going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure the nouveau drivers support that card yet, but the proprietary nvidia ones should. You should make sure your device is connected to the internet during installation, and select the "download updates while installing" as well as selecting non-free proprietary software for drivers.  Another potential issue could be invalid installation media -- you should verify the integrity/checksum of the downloaded ISO before writing to USB.

Comment: @Nmath I cannot install any drivers because the black screen appears right after I run the grub option. I also use verified ISO from official site, written on new USB stick made as described in official Ubuntu site.

Comment: @Nmath I have checked checksum on Windows 10 using Cygwin and `md5sum` utility, and it matches the checksum showed on the download site.

Comment: @sgnsajgon What is your laptop make and model?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ASUS ROG G703 GRIFFIN.

I have asked the same question on [official Asus Forum](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?119034-Cannot-install-Ubuntu-20-on-ASUS-ROG-G703-GRIFFIN)

Comment: Just a hint: make sure your Windows is not hibernated when you try to boot Ubuntu, Windows 10 leaves some odd state when it hibernates, and it hibernates by default on some laptops.

Comment: @GiovanniBeltrame No hibernation. Disabled in system.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your black screen is not related to graphics cards. Try adding `acpi=off` in the first instance, and experiment with other kernel command line options, such as `noapic` and `nolapic`.

If your kernel panics before it mounts a file system, you won't be able to get logs. In this instance, you can redirect console output to a USB/Serial device, which may give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem installing Debian on a laptop with the same Graphics Card. It simply was impossible for the reasons I describe here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/LinuxOnThinkpad/comments/mmw1sy/cant_start_debian_10_on_new_thinkpad_t15g_gen_1/

Maybe some of the things I did help you.

However, I must say that with Ubuntu 20.04 everything worked out of the box BUT the HDMI port, as I mention here:

[HDMI port not working with Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 card (on a ThinkPad T15g Gen 1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337308/hdmi-port-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04-and-nvidia-geforce-rtx-2080-card-on-a-t)

The reason it works with Ubuntu 20.04 is because Ubuntu has support for the Nvidia card thought it is far from perfect as the issue with the HDMI port shows. This means that, as someone else has mentioned, your case might be unrelated with the graphics card.