# HDMI port not working with Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 card (on a ThinkPad T15g Gen 1)

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I have a ThinkPad T15g Gen 1 fresh from the factory with Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 as its graphics processor. With Ubuntu 20.04 everything works out of the box but the HDMI port: the external monitor behaves as if it had no input at all, whereas in Windows the HDMI port works as expected.

Here is the solution for the Nvidia GT 620M card. I'd be very grateful if someone knows the solution for the Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 because it is quite confusing to get the right drivers! Thanks!

Comment: It is absolutely not confusing. First disable Secure Boot in UEFI, then boot Ubuntu, open Additional Drivers, select & apply the recommended version. Reboot. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but, what do you mean by "open Additional Drivers". In Ubuntu I can't find anything with  that name , and it is not an option in, say, "Settings". Maybe it is in the "Nvidia X server Settings" but that window  appears blank when I call it...

Comment: Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab or directly search for Additional Drivers. Just like searching any other installed software. If you already have Nvidia X Server settings then you already tried to install them by some means and if it appears blank either Secure Boot is active or the wrong drivers were installed. The method outlined above avoids the latter, it couldn't be easier and definitely not confusing.

Comment: @techmoerror220 did that wrk for you?